# How to fix crypto.pbkdf2 error on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, cryptojs

I'm attempting to add the crypto.pbkdf2 to my system and I keep returning a digest issue when using mocha to test the various functionalities. My code for the hash method is:

```
Account.prototype.hashPassword = function (password, salt, callback) {
// we use pbkdf2 to hash and iterate 10k times by default 
 var iterations = 10000,
    keylen = 64; //64 bit.
this.crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, keylen,'sha1', callback);
};
```

I've tried to change the digest ('sha1') to many things, including 'shah256', 'null' or digest. But my tests are still failing with the error:

```
 TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "digest" argument must be one of type string or null. Received type undefined
  at check (internal/crypto/pbkdf2.js:56:13)
  at Object.pbkdf2Sync (internal/crypto/pbkdf2.js:45:5)
  at UserMock.seedUsers (test\user-mock.js:32:39)
  at Context.<anonymous> (test\account-test.js:296:27)
```

How do I solve the error I am facing?

Comment: You get the same error every time?

Comment: Yeah, no matter what I change I seem to be getting the same error. I checked the node compatibility and that doesn't seem to be an issue.

Comment: Ok you would need to give more details like is it Node.js' internal crypto package? Where do you call this method? Also, is there any other place where you're using this method `crypto.pbkdf2`?

Comment: Yes, I'm calling the internal crypto package in Node.js. I'm creating log-in functionality, so the password, salt and callback are used in various other methods. I'm not using it anywhere else, only the variables are being used for the different log in screens.

Comment: `crypto.pbkdf2('password', 'salt', 10000, 64,'sha1', function () { console.log(arguments)})` works for me as expected. Can you replace with this and test? Also what version of Node.js are you using and what's `this.crypto` ? Shouldn't it be just `crypto`?

Comment: @tbking Thank you - I tried that and I'm still getting the same error message. I'm using node 10.15.0. The this.crypto is simply the variable I am calling, this.crypto = require('crypto');

Comment: @D.Shah, any progress on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You have probably fixed this by now, but just in case someone else also has this problem - as I did:
The functionality of the function `crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, iterations, keylen, digest)` changed in Node 6 to make ***digest*** compulsory.  Up until Node 10, if *digest* wasn't provided then 'sha1' was used. But Node 10 requires it.
Finding that out resolved my near as damn it identical message to the one you were getting.

Comment: What's this `digest` thing?

Comment: Does this mean that it's optional in Node 9?

Comment: Yes it does.  Until Node 10 came along this parameter was optional, the default value being sha1.